# Filtering from pandas pivot table by value in a row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I created a (large) sparse matrix by a pivot table.

```
UserId                                                               ...   
1         5.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   
2         NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   
3         NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   
4         NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   
5         NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   2.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   
...       ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...  ...   
6036      NaN   NaN   NaN   2.0   NaN   3.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   
6037      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   
6038      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   
6039      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   
6040      3.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   

MovieId  3943  3944  3945  3946  3947  3948  3949  3950  3951  3952  
UserId                                                               
1         NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
2         NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
3         NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
4         NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
5         NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
...       ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...  
6036      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
6037      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
6038      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
6039      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
6040      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Now, I am looking for a way for, given a row index (e.g. 1) select all index whose values are > 4.0. Is there a simple way to do so?.
I tried the following

```
df.loc[1] >= 4.0
```

however what I get is

```
MovieId
1        True
2       False
3       False
4       False
5       False
        ...  
3948    False
3949    False
3950    False
3951    False
3952    False
Name: 1, Length: 3706, dtype: bool
```

meaning I am almost there, but not quite. How do I extract the indices corresponding to `True`?

Comment: You've created a boolean mask of the dataframe, you just need to use it to mask the original df with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) `df[df.loc[1] >= 4.0]`

Comment: You want a Series for that specific row of only the columns for that row that are `>=4`?

Comment: Thank you @G.Anderson, However this solution does not work: `IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).`

Comment: Thanks @ALollz, yes, I would like the columns for that row that are `>=4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain two `loc` selections, the first selects the rows based on label, the second will use a function to subset the columns based on your condition. Or you could use a single nested loc, where the columns mask also calls `.loc`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([1, np.NaN, 5], p=[.2, .7, .1], size=(2, 40)))
```

---

```
df.loc[1].loc[lambda x: x >= 4]
#or 
df.loc[1, df.loc[1] >= 4]

#3     5.0
#10    5.0
#12    5.0
#15    5.0
#29    5.0
#Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you! however I think I just found another solution that better fits my needs.
`s = df.loc[1] >= 4.0` and hence `s[s].index.values`, which is actually your second answer

Comment: @Oscar you can add on a `.index` to the end of any of those to get the index values. Your method also works perfectly fine.